# Can I Make A Product Collection Use Flat Tables in Magento

Tags: magento

In my Magento store I currently have Flat Catalog Product turned Off because it breaks some custom code I have on my site.

However, I am have a single instance where it would greatly help me to have the collection use the flat table as opposed to the EAV tables.

Is there a way I can tell the product collection to use the flat tables as opposed to the EAV tables in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to fix your custom code :) In the default system, flat catalog is either turned on or off, not with any level of granularity. Depending on the nature of the hack that breaks the flat catalog, it may be possible to avoid that issue and just it turned on globally.

Perhaps more detail into the issue that caused you to leave it turned off?

Comment: You are correct. I managed to re-configure my product attribute to fix my problem.